# JSON request response type error - Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a Json request that i am sending for a django project. I am sending the request and I am getting a a response as I am expecting. But I think the response is coming back as a string and not as a file or iterable file. I am not sure how to ensure the response is the correct format to be processed. Here is the request that I am sending from the django views.py file...

```
def createUserSynapse(request):
    data = {
        "logins":[
            {
                "email":"test@test.com",
            }
        ],
        "phone_numbers":[
            "123.456.7890",
            "test@test.com",
        ],
        "legal_names":[
            "Test name",
        ],
        "extras":{
            "supp_id":"asdfe515641e56wg",
            "cip_tag":12,
            "is_business":False,
        }
    }

    req = urllib.request.Request('http://uat-api.synapsefi.com')
    req.add_header('X-SP-GATEWAY', 'client_id_asdfeavea561va9685e1gre5ara|client_secret_4651av5sa1edgvawegv1a6we1v5a6s51gv')
    req.add_header('X-SP-USER-IP', '127.0.0.1')
    req.add_header('X-SP-USER', '| ge85a41v8e16v1a618gea164g65')
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    print(req.headers)

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data).encode('utf8'))

    print(response)

    return render(reqest, 'tabs/create_user_synapse.html', response)
```

also, the second to last time is supposed to print the response and it is not printing anything....

can anyone help me... 
Here is the full error:

```
TypeError at /setup_profile/
POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/setup_profile/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py in do_request_, line 1248
Python Executable:  C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\Desktop\\opentab\\opentab',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 5 Sep 2017 06:17:10 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\Desktop\opentab\opentab\tab\views.py in profileSetup
                            createUserSynapse(request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\Desktop\opentab\opentab\tab\views.py in createUserSynapse
                response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data)) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen
                return opener.open(url, data, timeout) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py in open
                        req = meth(req) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py in do_request_
                            raise TypeError(msg) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: The traceback says `response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))` but your code has `.encode('utf8')`. You've copied something wrong.

Comment: Tried running this on python 3.6.1 and got 403 which suggested that there was not a problem with the encoding.